# How do you scrub a List for only matching strings?

Tags: c#, listbox, data-scrubbing

I am trying to create a routine that takes a List from a textBox and then scrubs it using another List.  Only strings with the matching text will remain.  I don't think I can use RegEx, because I don't know what the scrub list will consist of.  The match does not have to be absolute.  For example:

```
'ant' from my scrub list would match 'antiques', 'manta', 'ants', etc.
```

I thought I was on the right track with the following code, but I am getting red squigglies under both of the last two lines of code.  Any help is appreciated:

```
List<string> masterList = new List<string>(textBox_masterList.Text.Split(','));    
List<string> scrubList = new List<string>(textBox_scrubList.Text.Split(','));
for (int i = 0; i < masterList.Count; i++)
    masterList = masterList.Where(x => x.Contains(scrubList));
```

or

```
    masterList = masterList.RemoveAll(x => x.!Contains(scrubList));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how about `masterList.Intersect(scrubList);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> masterList = new List<string>(textBox_masterList.Text.Split(','));
List<string> scrubList = new List<string>(textBox_scrubList.Text.Split(','));
masterList = masterList.Where(x => scrubList.Any(s => x.Contains(s)))
                       .ToList();
```

To make search case-insensitive:

```
masterList = masterList.Where(x => scrubList.Any(s => 
                          Regex.IsMatch(x, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but it's looking at case.  Is there any way to disregard case?

Comment: @Jeagr see update - you can use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` for that.

Answer (score 3):

An efficient and short approach is using `Enumerable.Except`:

```
masterList = masterList.Except(scrubList).ToList();
```

If you want to use `RemoveAll` which doesn't need to create a temp list:

```
masterList.RemoveAll(str => scrubList.Contains(str));
```

Since you want to remove all string which are in `scrubList`.

**Edit**: to make it case-insensitive:

```
masterList.RemoveAll(str => scrubList.Any(s => s.Equals(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Nope, this will not check substrings

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: It's not clear that OP also wants to remove strings when it contains a "forbidden" string, is it?

Comment: Well, he mentioned that match does not have to be absolute, so I think simple Except will not fit here anyway..

Comment: Is there any way to disregard case?

Comment: Thanks again, Tim.  Wonderfully succinct answers.  I love short.

Answer (score 2):

The for statement is useless, you don't use the variable i.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code in hand but you can convert each `list` to a `datatable` then use the join. That should result as the initial list scrubbed down.